# How to Restrict user to add only one item to a Recyclerview from selecting just one particular item(id) in another Recyclerview?

Tags: android, validation, android-recyclerview

I have implemented Two Recyclerviews in my Android Project screen. First one has some items and an add button per each item. When that add button clicked user is shown to a dialog which takes inputs from user for that selected particular item and add that user data to another (second) recyclerview.

What i need to do is, to restrict the user to add only one entry per item in second recyclerview from first recyclerview selected item.

Let me explain an instance from the below screen. "User wants to add a price amount for contract code 1001 from first recyclerview. Then he clicks the Plus button in recyclerview item so he will input the price amount , after he saves that it will show up in the second recycler view with the adde price amount. What i want to do is, to not let the user to add another price amount for the same contract code 1001 again. If he again press on plus add button in recyclerview item 1001 from the first recyclerview he should not be able to add another price amount. But if he choose to delete the previously added price amount for item 1001, then the user should be permitted to add a new price amount entry for item 1001, to the second recyclerview."

I really appreciate an explanation of a way to achieve this and/or a code sample is more than welcome. Thank you in advance.

[UI Screen for The Two RecyclerViews](https://i.stack.imgur.com/96fnz.png)

Comment: What you have tried so far?

Comment: i have tried to pass the item id and check whether it has a non empty value added in the second recyclerview with the same item id.

Answer (score 0):

Provide an unique attribute to the item of first RecyclerView which you are adding to second RecyclerView. Whenever you add item to second RecyclerView, check that item is already there or not.
You can use boolean to save state and all.

```
 boolean setnews = false;
```

Comment: i'm not following what you say.. can you explain a bit more please?

Comment: You want to transfer item from one recycerView to another without redundancy.Right?